# Identify EC curve in certificate using openssl api

Tags: openssl, certificate

I am trying to display some certificate information on the screen and curve used for key generation is giving me trouble. In the [certificate example](http://lapo.it/asn1js/#308201153081BDA003020103020101300A06082A8648CE3D0403023000301E170D3134303631353232303030305A170D3139303631353232303030305A30003059301306072A8648CE3D020106082A8648CE3D03010703420004D08D53D9EFF34F662639822B99AEFFC2DD7916E535C01C4CB862296360F293589B0F95C344744DE0123D8D4CF89EB29D37D91D1FF327C2AD0FB182A7A2582518A328302630240603551D11041D301BA019060504007F0007A0100C0E3149534B30303030303030303031300A06082A8648CE3D0403020347003044022070DEB8246B5311115302CBC62B5E0713A1B9637344E1548A90B5503590C531600220244DC07B996B60362AD14758CE649BF4481D05D3C4D28DCA2B7E7126C54F4C72) curve used is properly identified as prime256v1. However I would like to obtain this information using the the OpenSsl api. What function accomplishes this?

I am using ManagedOpenSsl but it does not really matter. The thing is I could find examples in C for every other problem I had, but not for this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OpenSSL wiki has a page with some of this stuff at [Elliptic Curve Cryptography](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Cryptography). Most of the EC functions you need are in `<openssl src dir>/crypto/ec/ec.h`.

You have to extract the public key from the certificate with `EVP_PKEY* pkey=X509_get_pubkey(x509)`.

Check the key type with `EVP_PKEY_get_type(pkey)`. It should return `EVP_PKEY_EC`. You need to write `EVP_PKEY_get_type`. Here it is:

```
int EVP_PKEY_get_type(EVP_PKEY *pkey)
{
    ASSERT(pkey);
    if (!pkey)
        return NID_undef;

    return EVP_PKEY_type(pkey->type);
}
```

You fetch the key with `EC_KEY* key = EVP_PKEY_get1_EC_KEY(pkey)`. Since its a `get1`, it bumps the reference count on the `EC_KEY*`. Be sure to call `EC_KEY_free` on it. (A `get0` would *not* require a free).

*If* `OPENSSL_EC_NAMED_CURVE` is set, then you can use `EC_GROUP_get_curve_name`. It will return a *NID* for for the curve used (more correctly, the domain parameters). For example, `prime256v1` will return `NID_X9_62_prime256v1`.

Otherwise, you need to fetch the domain parameters like `curve`, `G`, `h`, etc one-by-one with `EC_GROUP_get_curve_GFp` (or `EC_GROUP_get_curve_GF2m`), `EC_GROUP_get_order`, and friends.

`OPENSSL_EC_NAMED_CURVE` is a flag. You can fetch the flags with `EC_GROUP_get_asn1_flag` and test for it with `flag & OPENSSL_EC_NAMED_CURVE`.

You can see an example of both named curves and non-named curves at [Named Curves](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Cryptography#Named_Curves). More than likely, you will have a named curve. In the case of OpenSSL, omitting the `OPENSSL_EC_NAMED_CURVE` flag results in a handshake failure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, jww. Is it correct that you mean that get1 "bumps the reference count on the EVP_PKEY*" (not EC_KEY*) in the first paragraph after the code snippet?